# Is using two lock statements one after another thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock, dining-philosopher

I've been learning about multi-thread programming and working on the dining philosophers problem. I'm trying to **cause** a deadlock **without** sleeping any threads. Here is the code snippet that I'm using:

```
public class Program
    {
        const int NumberOfPhilosophers = 5;
        const int NumberOfForks = 5;
        const int EatingTimeInMs = 20;
        static object[] forks = new object[NumberOfForks];
        static Thread[] philosopherEatingThreads = new Thread[NumberOfPhilosophers];

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfForks; i++)
            {
                forks[i] = new object();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPhilosophers; i++)
            {
                int philosopherIndex = i;

                philosopherEatingThreads[i] = new Thread(() => { DoWork(philosopherIndex); })
                {
                    Name = philosopherIndex.ToString()
                };

                philosopherEatingThreads[philosopherIndex].Start();
            }

        }

        public static void DoWork(int philosopherIndex)
        {
            int fork1Index = philosopherIndex;
            int fork2Index = (philosopherIndex + 1 ) % NumberOfForks;
            var fork1 = forks[fork1Index];
            var fork2 = forks[fork2Index];

            lock (fork1)
            {
                lock (fork2)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(EatingTimeInMs);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I wasn't able to see any deadlocks after trying a couple of times. I know that not experiencing a deadlock **does not** mean that this code is thread-safe.
For example, when I change the lock statement and add latency I cause deadlock.

```
lock (fork1)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    lock (fork2)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(EatingTimeInMs);
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is using two lock statements one after another an atomic operation?
2. If using Thread.Sleep() causes a deadlock in a code snippet, does that mean that the code snippet is **not** thread-safe?

Thank you!

Comment: They're not atomic, they're two distinct operations, the first can succeed while the other might not/wait forever. A deadlock can occur if you every try to lock A then B in one thread and in another thread simultaneously try to lock B then A, the two threads might grab their first lock and then deadlock waiting for the other to be released.

Comment: So my code is not thread-safe then, right?

Comment: No, that code is not threadsafe. Failure to provoke an error does not mean that the error cannot occur. That is one of the reasons multi threaded programming is so difficult.

Comment: Your code is not safe from possible deadlocks cause your are taking different locks in different order.

Comment: @HansPassant - how not? It's the classic circular wait for locks. E.g. with just two threads and two locks, thread 1 locks `forks[0]` then tries to lock `forks[1]` and thread 2 does the opposite.

Comment: What's revealing is that a) you have to ask if it's thread safe and b) other developers look at it, have a hard time answering the question, and disagree with each other. That means regardless of whether it will work as intended, it's very difficult to reason on.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Do you think this code snippet thread safe?

Comment: It's not safe from deadlocks, if that's what you mean. "thread safe" is a nebulous/ill-defined term.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant by "thread-safe".  Thanks!